# Boxlayouts with JPanels incorrectly expanding with resize

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager

I've searched a fair amount and I cannot locate a good, simple answer to this problem.

I want a box layout (superPanel), which contains an upper and lower JPanel (mainPanel and footerPanel). The upper will contain further JPanels (leftPanel and rightPanel).

Consider the code below, I find that when I resize the window, the mainPanel gets larger, and so does the footer. The footer should always stay the same size, below the mainPanel, at the bottom of the frame.

```
frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                JPanel container = new JPanel();
                container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JPanel superPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel rightPanel= new JPanel();
        JPanel footerPanel = new JPanel();

        footerPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        mainPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);

        mainPanel.add(leftPanel);
        mainPanel.add(rightPanel);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));


        leftPanel.add(new JButton("left"));
        rightPanel.add(new JButton("right"));
        footerPanel.add(new JButton("footer"));

        container.add(mainPanel);
        container.add(footerPanel);



        frame.add(container);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

Anybody know why this is occurring? If you run this you'll see that red and green both grow in size as the window is resized. What I want to see is the red getting larger, while the green remains the same size.

Glue doesn't work, and I don't want to have to use GridBagLayout unless I have to (please explain why I should if need be)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want a "main" section and side sections which don't change size, you usually want a BorderLayout:

```
container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

container.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
container.add(footerPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

Comment: Ah that looks better... Now in the upper panel can I do this: I want the leftPanel to have a specified width (say 100), but the right to fill up all the availale remaining space of the main panel. Is this easy to achieve? Should the main panel layout style still be a borderLayout?

Comment: Setting components' sizes to exact pixel amounts is not recommended, as fonts can vary between platforms (and look-and-feels).  You probably do want mainPanel to also use a (separate) BorderLayout, then add the leftPanel using the BorderLayout.LINE_START constraint and the rightPanel using the BorderLayout.CENTER constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) with fill.BOTH, weightx = 1 and weighty = 1 for the main panel and fill.NONE, weightx = 0 and weighty = 0  for the footer panel or use [Miglayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) which is really easy and with it you can do all what you want.

Answer (score 0):

BorderLayout is what you want on your container, adding the mainPanel to the center and footerPanel to the south. Try the following changes on your code:

```
    frame = new JFrame("Frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel container = new JPanel();
    container.setLayout(new BorderLayout());  // Use BorderLayout instead of BoxLayout

    JPanel superPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel footerPanel = new JPanel();

    footerPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    mainPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);

    mainPanel.add(leftPanel);
    mainPanel.add(rightPanel);
    mainPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));

    leftPanel.add(new JButton("left"));
    rightPanel.add(new JButton("right"));
    footerPanel.add(new JButton("footer"));

    container.add(mainPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);    // Add mainPanel to the central area
    container.add(footerPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);   // Add footePanel to the bottom

    frame.add(container);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

The BorderLayout determines that a component added to the CENTER area will expand both horizontally and vertically to follow the container. The SOUTH area can only expand horizontally while EAST and WEST can only expand vertically. Keep in mind that every layout manager class has its own rules on how to divide the container space among components and how they are resized.